# Когда можно использовать imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap). Чем еще кроме канвас динамично менять изображение в ImageView

Tags: java, android, canvas, imageview

вот есть у меня imageview , если в методе onCreate я присваиваю imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap), то всё нормально отображается.  А если в каком нибудь другом методе после того, как метод onCreate сработал, получаю ошибку Ссылка на нулевой объект. Т.е. метод setImageBitmap не годится для того , чтобы в процессе работы приложения динамично менять изображение в ImageView? А если я хочу в одном ImageView получать различные изображения, то как быть?

```
   Убрал всё лишнее в коде. Как видите внизу есть Set метод . И если с другого класса пытаюсь присвоить изображение получаю ошибку. А если сразу в OnCreate присваивать то изображение появляется. Но мне нужно в дальнейшем часто менять этот ImageView

     public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity {



        ImageView imageView1,imageView2,imageView3,imageView4,imageView5,imageView6,imageView7;
        Bitmap[] myArray = new Bitmap[11]; 


        @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
            mainGamePanel =  (MainGamePanel) findViewById(R.id.surface);

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.one);
            imageView1 = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            imageView2 = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            imageView3 = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            imageView4 = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
            imageView5 = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
            imageView6 = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
            imageView7 = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView7);

            myArray[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.zero0);
            myArray[1] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.one);
            myArray[2] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.two);
            myArray[3] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.three);
            myArray[4] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.four);
            myArray[5] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.five);
            myArray[6] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.six);
            myArray[7] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.seven);
            myArray[8] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.eight);
            myArray[9] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.nine);
            myArray[10] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.point);

        }

        public void SetTime (int Seconds1){
            imageView1.setImageBitmap(myArray[Seconds1]);
        }

}
```

Set метод я вызываю из класса который объявлен в этой разметке

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="example.igeniy.Menu">


    <view
        class="example.igeniy.MainGamePanel"
        android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </view>

    <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

</FrameLayout>
```

Пытаюсь вызвать в конце метода конструктора

```
public class MainGamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {



    private static final String TAG = MainThread.class.getSimpleName();
    private MainThread thread;
    private Chronometer Treadchronometer;
    private mainCharacter Character, Character1, Character2, Character3, Character4;
    private Time time;
    Menu menu = new Menu();
    Bitmap[] myArray = new Bitmap[11];
    SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;


    public MainGamePanel(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            // Для устройств до Android 5
            createOldSoundPool();
        } else {
            // Для новых устройств
            createNewSoundPool();
        }

        mAssetManager = getContext().getAssets();
        // получим идентификаторы
        sExplosion = loadSound("explosion.wav");
        getHolder().addCallback(this);

        touchpad = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.touchpad);
        myArray[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.zero0);
        myArray[1] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.one);
        myArray[2] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.two);
        myArray[3] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.three);
        myArray[4] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.four);
        myArray[5] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.five);
        myArray[6] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.six);
        myArray[7] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.seven);
        myArray[8] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.eight);
        myArray[9] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.nine);
        myArray[10] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.point);
        NewGame();

        setFocusable(true);

        menu.SetTime(5);   // ВОТ ТУТ ПЫТАЮСЬ ВЫЗВАТЬ Сеттер

    }





    public void NewGame (){
        Character = new  mainCharacter(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), face_box), 10, 10, 100, 100);
        Character1 = new mainCharacter(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.face_circle_tiled), 50, 300, 100, 100);
        Character2 = new mainCharacter(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.face_circle_tiled), 400, 200, 100, 100);
        Character3 = new mainCharacter(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.face_circle_tiled), 300, 30, 100, 100);
        Character4 = new mainCharacter(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.face_circle_tiled), 34, 30, 100, 100);

    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        Log.d(TAG,"surfaceChanged");
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start();
        Treadchronometer = new Chronometer();
        Treadchronometer.setRunning(true);
        Treadchronometer.start();
    }




    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            destroy();
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {}


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // Заливаем canvas белым цветом
        canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(190, 223, 220)); // PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR - используется, чтобы ничего не отображать подробнее в PorterDuff режимы
        // Вызываем метод, который выводит рисунок главного персонажа
        canvas.drawBitmap(touchpad, 0, menu.getHeight() * 0.7F, null);
        Character1.draw(canvas);
        Character2.draw(canvas);
        Character3.draw(canvas);
        Character4.draw(canvas);
        Character.draw(canvas);
    }


}
```

Comment: При чем же метод? Видимо, нет самого bitmap'а.
Приложите код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот, например, рабочий код. Всё хорошо меняется.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Bitmap bitmap1;
Bitmap bitmap2;
ImageView view;
boolean whatBitmap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test);
    bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.testtwo);

}
public void click(View v)
{
    if (whatBitmap) {
    view.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
        whatBitmap = false;
    }
    else {
        view.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);
        whatBitmap = true;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: хм. Значит ошибка , в чем то другом..Если я перемещаю imageView1.setImageBitmap(myArray[5]); в методы OnResume , OnCreate , он срабатывает, а как пытаюсь вызвать его из класса определенного в разметке получаю ошибку..

Comment: Покажите, где и как Вы его вызываете.

Comment: приложил код . Вызываю в конце метода конструктора. Может проблема в том, что этот класс объявлен в разметке . Я попробовал вызвать сеттер через код исполняемый в доп.потоке, но вышла ошибка : Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views .